# can't open web pages in google chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I type in google chrome "google.com" I receive such error:

```
404. That’s an error.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/authme?s=0.2068704296834766 was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

It seems I'm redirected somehow by some reason.
Probably lenovo notebook problem?
At the same time IE works fine.

This problem reproducable with other webpages too, for example i'm redirected from vkontakte.ru to such web page which doesn't exist too `http://www.vkontakte.ru/cgi-bin/authme?s=0.7140683813486247`

Also I see such message when chrome starts "Lütfen yönlendirilirken bekleyin", this is very strange because I only have russian and english languages installed in system.

Comment: Check your hosts file for any uncommon entries, also make sure you have an AV scanner with recent definitions installed and perform a full system scan. Disable any extensions in chrome and try again

Comment: hosts file is empty, chrome doesn't have any extensions, AV scanner didn't found anything

Comment: It seems like that your traffic is being hijacked by some malware, injecting the authme parameters.  The question is where - if it isn't an extension, and av isn't showing anything.  Perhaps a proxy server?

Comment: why someone need to add "authme=....." to url? i don't use proxy server either...

Comment: @Paul also "authme=" injected in completely different networks (even when i'm in different countries), so problem must be on my local computer

Comment: The authme is likely to be to command and control, your connection is redirected to a controlled site, your browser authenticates, and recieves instructions.  Of course it could be something benign that is behaving weirdly.  Are you running minecraft?

Comment: @Paul no, i don't have any games installed. The question is who how and why redirects me....

Comment: you really should search google for help removing malware/adware from Windows and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear google browsing data and you are done. I experienced the same after some mcafee proxy software directed my browser to a login page.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after visiting Turkey (same Turkish redirect message). Clearing browsing data didn't work for me, as I did not want to erase everything.
in the end I found the solution by going to HTTP/SSL settings in Chrome advanced settings and delete the entries related to wifi access points I used during my visit to Turkey.

This did the trick. Probably my hotel (Gezi) or the airport.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after returning from Turkey. For Mozilla, you need to go to

**Tools** --> **Options** --> **Advanced** --> **Certificates**.

Once there *See Certificates*, *Authorities* and delete everything that looks like Turkish. It worked perfect for me just with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error and obviously is very open-ended with errors/solutions.

Basically you can either go down the route of process of elimination, or just simply attempt different solutions (after each solution, reset Google Chrome).

I have a couple of solutions you could try...

- Chrome < Settings < Advanced Settings - Under Privacy, un-tick the box that says 'predict network actions...'

Also check for Google Chrome updates...

Lastly, you could reinstall Google Chrome altogether, often malware can be affiliated with a continued instance (instance that can be closed) of a program. Therefore, the only possible way is to uninstall and reinstall Google Chrome.